# How to implement new diameter application on Mobicent jain-slee platform?

Tags: java, restcomm, mobicents, jain-slee

I am working on Mobicent Jain Slee platform (2.7.0). I need to implement a new diameter application (sd interface) that is not currently implemented.
Based on jDiameter [docs](https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter)

> It also features an extensible architecture that allows additional Diameter application modules to be plugged in

So anyone can provide steps on how to start or any helpful resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobicents has been rebranded to Restcomm.
Please use the latest Restcomm JAIN SLEE 2.8 release. More documentation on both JAIN SLEE and jDiameter from http://documentation.telestax.com/core/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @jeand. I will use the latest JAIN SLEE release. However, would you give hints on how to start developing the new application. Should i start from jDiameter to add the new application and then go jain slee diameter to implement the adaptor? .. Or it is only configurations should be applied to jDiameter and jain-slee diameter ? Appreciate your help ..

Comment: You need to use JAIN SLEE directly to develop your application and use the JAIN SLEE jDiameter Resource Adaptors that wraps the jDiameter stack

Comment: you mean that there is no changes on jDiameter itself, only on the JAIN SLEE Diameter Resource Adapter ?

Comment: If you need some addition to jDiameter and implement Sd, please create an issue on https://github.com/RestComm/jdiameter for discussion and to contribute it through a Pull Request first. You will need to sign the CLA at https://telestax.com/acknowledgements/ too for your contribution to be accepted.

Comment: just need an advise, I have added a new SBB that holds an a custom Event and expose it within a service. I have deployed my DU and sent a request for that event and Diameter MUX catched the request and passed it the Resource Adapter. The Resource Adapter processed the requested and started activity for that session (in log: `Activity started [Diameter Session ID[OurSessionId1:1469721197532]]`) BUT unfortunately my SBB couldn't catch the event. What do you think the problem is ? knowing that i could catch other events (like CCA). working on last JAIN SLEE release.